# Using rel="noopener" in window.open()

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, target, window.opener

So I know that I can apply `rel="noopener` in an `a` tag when using `target="_blank"`. But I'm trying to pass it as an argument to `window.open()`, ie:

`window.open('http://cats.com', '_blank', 'rel=noopener')`

however it doesn't seem to be working the way that I expected, as the `opener` object still exists on the window after the user clicks on the link.

Is there something I'm missing? Or cannot it not be done the way that I'm intending?

I've found some great articles but they don't quite address my use case as far as I can tell.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open
https://mathiasbynens.github.io/rel-noopener/

Much appreciated.

Comment: The window feature flag string, as used in `window.open()`, is just `noopener` and not `rel=noopener`. The solution [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47634819/656132) has the best backwards and cross-browser compatibility, however.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There is no direct example in [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open#noopener) but it can be used like this and it worked for me.

```
window.open('http://cats.com', '_blank', 'noopener,resizable,scrollbars')
```

Comment: It is available in the documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open#Window_functionality_features as "Window functionality features" is part of the "Window features" is third argument of the window.open method.

Answer (score 13):

### Cover all your bases

The safest way to redirect is by adding `noopener`, `noreferrer`, and `window.opener = null`.

```
const openInNewTab = (url) => {
    const newWindow = window.open(url, '_blank', 'noopener,noreferrer')
    if (newWindow) newWindow.opener = null
}
```

Then call your new funtion

```
openInNewTab('https://stackoverflow.com')
```

The third param can also take [these optional values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open#Window_features), based on your needs.

Comment: `noreferrer` implies `noopener`, so only the `noreferrer` is required to have them both active.
"8. If noreferrer is true, then set noopener to true." from https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/window-object.html#apis-for-creating-and-navigating-browsing-contexts-by-name

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, this cannot be achieved with `window.open()` arguments.  There is, however, is a way to get the behavior:

```
var newWindow = window.open();
newWindow.opener = null;
newWindow.location = 'http://some.url';
```

Comment: not working in the latest chrome Version 88.0.4324.190 (Official Build) (64-bit).  rel = 'noreferrer' worked for me

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me:

```
const a = document.createElement("a")
a.href = args.url
a.target = "_blank"
a.rel = "noopener"
a.click()
```

Comment: So simple. Thanks!

Comment: This does not answer the posters question and is not a good coding style as it creates a fake element instead of using a built in function.
This should be the accepted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49918599/7905854