# Window.open with 'noopener' opens a new window instead of a new tab

Tags: javascript, window.open, window.opener

I was using `window.open('')` with `'_blank'` as second parameter to open my link in new tab For eg. `window.open('http://google.com', '_blank')`

But, recently I added the third parameter `'noopener'` so that `window.opener` becomes null in the new tab and the new tab does not have access to the parent tab/window. i.e. `window.opener` is `null`

`window.open('http://google.com', '_blank', 'noopener')`

So the above code solved the security problem, but instead of opening a new tab, a new window started opening which is not what I expected. My browser settings were same and no changes were made to it.

Is there anything I can do to make this code open new tab instead of new window ? I do not want to remove `noopener` as third parameter

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using rel="noopener" in window.open()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46147949/using-rel-noopener-in-window-open)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate, the link @Stender posted is about not getting "noopener" to work, not about it changed the tab/window behavior. Does this happen in all browsers the same? It could be a browser bug/inconsistency.

Comment: Yes, It worked same for me in Chrome, Firefox and IE

Comment: I suppose the correct syntax would be `noopener=1/true/yes`. It looks like all the other window features would be somehow connected to a window with a chrome, and `noopener` is the only one which actually is usefull also in tabs. Maybe that has been forgotten in browser implementations, and when the windowFeature argument is present, the window will be opened to a new window instead of a tab automatically. I made a small test with FF, and it opens a new window if the windowFeatures argument is present, the value of the argument doesn't matter, it can even be gibberish ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Honestly i think your code is fine but you can try a different implementation:

```
var yourWindow = window.open();
yourWindow.opener = null;
yourWindow.location = "http://someurl.here";
yourWindow.target = "_blank";
```

Comment: Note that using yourWindow.target = "_self" does not seem to work as intended in Safari as of 3/31/2020. Use, var yourWindow = window.open("http://someurl.here", "_self"); yourWindow.opener = null;

Answer (score 12):

Another approach that will solve this in one line is to access the opener property directly and set it to null to make use of the fact that `window.open()` returns a `Window` object. This will work across all browsers to open a new tab with a null `window.opener`.

```
window.open(url, '_blank').opener = null;
```

Comment: Looks a bit hacky, but this is the only solution, I found, which works reliably in all modern browsers.

Answer (score 5):

> https://mathiasbynens.github.io/rel-noopener/

```
const anchor = document.createElement('a');

Object.assign(anchor, {
  target: '_blank',
  href: 'http://google.com',
  rel: 'noopener noreferrer'
})
.click()
```

This is the method which feels a bit cleaner. It creates an anchor tag and clicks it, we have to use this workaround as its a user preference.

Answer (score 5):

This is the only thing that works cross-browser (IE11, Chrome 66, FF 60, Safari 11.1) for me

```js
function openURL(url) {
  var link = document.createElement('a');
  link.target = "_blank";
  link.href = url;
  link.rel = "noopener noreferrer";
  document.body.appendChild(link); // you need to add it to the DOM to get FF working
  link.click();
  link.parentNode.removeChild(link); // link.remove(); doesn't work on IE11
};
```